# Каков способ образования слова "ожёг"?

Tags: словообразование

Отличаются ли по морфемному составу слова *ожог* и *ожёг*? На одном из сайтов в слове *ожёг* указан нулевой суффикс.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Каков способ образования слова “ожёг”
```

(что сделал?)ОЖЁГ-нач.форма ожечь от жечь - с помощью приставки, значит, приставочный способ образования.

(что?)ожог- от ожечь с помощью чередования о//е, г//ч + нулевая суффиксация - бессуффиксный способ образования.

```
 Отличаются ли по морфемному составу слова ожог и ожёг? На одном 
 из сайтов  в слове ожёг указан нулевой суффикс.
```

Кто  признаёт нулевой суффикс, кто нет, хотя он действительно проявляется в форме прош. времени.Некоторые учёные говорят только о словообразующих нулевых суффиксах, другие выделяют и формообразующие.Думаю, это правильно.

Comment: Людмила, по сути не спорю, даже плюсанул от души. Но мне опять режет глаз слово бессуфиксный. Это новая мода так называть "бессуфиксальный"?

Comment: Это не мода, это принятый термин. У нас же в науке несколько школ, каждая даёт свой термин.Кто называет бессуффиксный, кто бессуффиксальный. кто -нулевая суффиксация  - всё одно-морфологический способ словообразования с участием нулевого суффикса, т.е. без суффикса.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Просто не слышал такого варианта. И поиском не встречается.

Answer (score 0):

В глаголе "ожёг" действительно нулевое окончание. Ожег - прош. время от глагола "ожечь". Слово "ожог" - существительное,  образовалось от глагола "ожег" с помощью приставки "о". У них общий корень - *жг*.

Comment: Серж, а нулевой суффикс в слове "ожёг" есть? Я спрашиваю потому, что нужно указать пары слов с одинаковым морфемным составом. На сайте http://udarenieru.ru/index.php?morph_word=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&word=on  указан нулевой суффикс.

Comment: Да, нулевой суффикс есть. В этом слове должен был быть формообразующий суффикс прошедшего времени -л. Но он не представлен. Ср.: ожег -обожг/л/а. Здесь л - формообразующий суффикс прошедшего времени, а -окончание.

Comment: Но я вам не советую обращаться к этому словарю за морфемным разбором. Там не всегда правильно разбирается морфемный состав, и бывают ошибки.

Comment: _Серж: "ожечь"... "ожог"... Оба слова образовались **от глагола "жечь"** с помощью приставки "о"_. === **Нет!** Слово "ожог" образовано от глагола "ожечь".

Comment: См.: [Правило «Правописание гласных после шипящих» в пособии Л.В. Балашовой, В.В. Дементьева «Курс русского языка»](http://www.licey.net/russian/phonetics/1_12)

Comment: _Серж: См.: Правило..._ === Посмотрел. Ну и? По-моему, в этом правиле ни Балашова, ни Дементьев не говорят, что слово "ожог" образовано от глагола "жечь" _**с помощью приставки "о"**_ (как это написано у Вас). "Жечь" стоит в начале словообразовательной цепочки, и от него с помощью приставки "о" образовано **только** слово _ожечь_. _Ожог_ же образован от глагола _ожечь_, уже имеющего приставку.  Словообразовательная цепочка: жечь -> **о**-жечь (вот именно здесь появляется приставка!) -> ожог@ (Грамота.ру: _"этот способ называют бессуффиксным, безаффиксным или нулевой суффиксацией"_).

Comment: Там же было написано: слова образованные от глагола жечь: ожег, ожог. Хотя с вами согласен. дополню ответ.

Comment: Уважаемые Людмила, Серж и slava! Дайте мне, пожалуйста, однозначный ответ: слова "ожёг" и "ожог" имеют одинаковый морфемный состав?

Comment: В слове "Ожог'' не выделяется приставка ''о". Оно образовано от глагола "ожег". В одном случае у нас приставочный способ образования, в другом - бессуффиксный способ образования.

Comment: *В глаголе "ожёг" действительно нулевое окончание* - вообще-то окончание никогда не было словообразующим элементом. Если вы этого не знаете, то вам лучше не отвечать на подобные вопросы.

Comment: *Дайте мне, пожалуйста, однозначный ответ: слова "ожёг" и "ожог"* - можно я отвечу? 1. Ваш вопрос не об этом был, а о способе образования. Одно из другого не вытекает. 2. Сам по себе вопрос хороший. Надо бы отдельной темой, кстати. А вот ответ на него не может быть однозначным. Во-первых, считать ли "жег" и "жог" одним корнем или разными. А во-вторых и в-главных, у глагола нулевой суффикс скорее всего есть, хотя тоже можно спорить. но вот у существительного его выделить весьма сложно. Поэтому скорее всего и морфемный состав следует признать разным. Но это сильно зависит от точки зрения.

Comment: *В слове "Ожог'' не выделяется приставка ''о".* - это как же вас понимать, уважаемый? Если приставка не выделяется, то тогда каков корень? Что-то совсем Вы заплутали в трех соснах... Кстати, вопрос способа словообразования имеет весьма косвенное отношения к вопросу о том, одинаковый ли морфемный состав.

Comment: Если вы не знаете, что словообразовательный и словообразующий -то же самое, вам тоже не стоит отвечать на подобные вопросы.

Comment: Насчет того,что словообразование имеет косвенное отношение к морфемному составу - это не ко мне. Автор спрашивал,одинаковый лиморфемный состав у этих слов. А я ответил.

Comment: Т.е. свою великую мысль про приставку пояснить ничего не можете, кроме "сам дурак"? Тогда я вам прямо говорю. В слове "Ожог" ***выделяется*** приставка, Вы написали глупость.

Comment: *А я ответил* - вот я и говорю, что с Вам не следует отвечать на вопросы, если вы раз за разом показываете свою некомпетентность.

Comment: Зато Вы показываете свою "грамотность"! Все тупые - Вы один грамотный! Если вы ставите под сомнение даже знаменитых лингвистов! Что с вами говорить! Остальное - не ваше дело! В чужом глазу соринку видите - в своем бревно не замечаете!

Comment: Только и спорами  занимаетесь! Никто ничего не понимает,кроме вас!

Answer (score 0):

> Дайте мне, пожалуйста, однозначный ответ: слова "ожёг" и "ожог" имеют
>   одинаковый морфемный состав?

Однозначный ответ можно было бы дать, если бы автор задания сказал, **на какой из учебников он ориентировался при составлении этого задания**.

***Однозначного*** ответа невозможно дать, к примеру, на вопрос: *чем является **-ть** в глаголах -- суффиксом или окончанием?*

Почему? Да потому что в одних учебниках у одних лингвистов это ***-ть*** названо суффиксом, в других учебниках у других лингвистов -- окончанием.

***Однозначного*** ответа невозможно дать и на вопрос: *каков статус суффиксов причастий и деепричастий? Какие они: словообразовательные или формообразовательные?*

Почему нельзя дать *однозначный* ответ? Да потому что в одних учебниках причастия и деепричастия считаются формами глагола, в других -- самостоятельными частями речи.  И в первом случае эти суффиксы -- формообразовательные, во втором -- словообразовательные.

***Однозначного*** ответа невозможно дать даже на такой простой вопрос: *чем является **по-** в слове **поезд** -- приставкой или частью корня?*  В разных словарях Вы увидите разный разбор...

Что же до слов "ожёг" и "ожог"…

Да, можно, наверное, было бы говорить об одинаковом морфемном составе этих слов: **приставка + корень + нулевой суффикс** (в случае с "ожёг" -- формообразовательный, в случае с "ожог" -- словообразовательный) **+ нулевое окончание.** Можно было бы… если бы все лингвисты и все учебники и учебные пособия описывали словообразование этих слов одинаково. Но, к сожалению, *одинаковости* нет и здесь.  Где-то способ образования отглагольных существительных типа ***ожог*** называется **нулевой суффиксацией** (и тогда в этом слове будет суффикс, пусть и нулевой), где-то --  **бессуффиксным способом** образования (и в этом случае **не все** лингвисты усматривают нулевой суффикс  в словах типа ***ожог***).

А потому однозначно ответить на вопрос, одинаков ли  морфемный состав  у слов "ожёг" и "ожог", сможет, думаю, только составитель этого задания.

Comment: slava1947, у вас так много отвлеченных рассуждений на тему "на какие еще вопросы нельзя дать однозначного ответа", хотя это и так ясно, что терминологические споры в лингвистике бесконечны и никогда до добра не доводили. Но я не понял главного. Разве только различием терминологии объясняется невозможность дать ответ? Неужели вы сути не заметили? Спор ведь не только и не столько о том, как назвать эту ситуацию "отсутствие суффикса" или "нулевой суффикс", это и яйца бы выеденного не стоило. Вы, боюсь, не поняли главного.

Comment: Речь не о названии, а о сути этого самого нулевого суффикса. Существует ли он как формообразующая и/или словообразующая единица, или же его просто нет в данном конкретном слове. Это принципиально разные ситуации с точки зрения классификации морфемного состава. Поэтому спор этот принципиальный, а не терминологический.

Comment: _behemothus: Речь не о названии, а о сути этого самого нулевого суффикса. Существует ли он как формообразующая и/или словообразующая единица, или же его просто нет в данном конкретном слове._ === У одних лингвистов -- существует, у других -- нет. Я же написал в своём ответе:  _...где-то -- бессуффиксным способом образования (**и в этом случае не все лингвисты усматривают нулевой суффикс в словах типа ожог**)_.

Comment: *У одних лингвистов -- существует, у других -- нет.* - значит, и правда, не поняли. Или я Вас не понимаю...

Comment: Кто-то, может, и не понял...  Но это точно не я. Из учебника "Современный русский язык" (М., 1997) под ред. Белошапковой:

_Нулевая суффиксация иногда рассматривается как бессуфиксный способ образования. При таком подходе не даётся ответа на вопрос, какое средство является выразителем деривационного значения…_

Comment: Ну и как Вы понимаете процитированную вами фразу? Я именно так, что проблема не в том, "усматривают" ли лингвисты нулевой суффикс, а в том, существует ли он вообще. Хотя согласен, написано так, что врагу не пожелаешь разбираться, но все-таки разница подходов явно не в терминологии.

Comment: _behemothus: проблема не в том, "усматривают" ли лингвисты нулевой суффикс, а в том, **существует ли он вообще**_. === Лет 50-60 назад его вообще не существовало. А сейчас он существует только у тех лингвистов, кто его признаёт. К примеру, есть у Литневской -- и в глаголах, и в существительных. Но в справочнике для школьников Е.А. Пановой (М., 2010) он есть только в глаголах, в существительных же, образованных бессуффиксным способом, его в этом справочнике нет. А в  справочнике этом написано: _Материалы книги соответствуют формату Единого государственного экзамена..._